# python3.8 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig' and other fun errors

Tags: 16.04, python3

All i am trying to do is install and use matplotlib.

I use ROS on Ubuntu 16.04. Although ROS has nothing to do with my goal now, I am aware that because ros kinetic uses python2.7, sourcing catkin workspaces is tricky because I need to have python2.7 in the PYTHONPATH for ros, but if I need to use python3.8 for matplotlib it also must be in the PYTHONPATH. I am not too familiar with how python is handled on linux but I have learned a lot trying to solve this.

python version is Python 2.7.12

python3 version is Python 3.8.5 which I updated using [this website](https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

pip and pip3 version results with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/.local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    vendored("requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/packages/ordered_dict.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 70, in <module>
    Iterable.register(str)
AttributeError: type object 'Iterable' has no attribute 'register'
```

It is very possible that I simply do not have pip installed. This was a problem I had previously, and I was able to install pip3 correctly but I guess it is broken once again.

my PYTHONPATH environment variables are :/usr/lib/python3.8:/usr/lib/python2.7

The last few lines of my .bashrc which should be the only few that matter in this case are:

```
#source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
#source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

#source ~/Documents/ROS/SRCAutoCar/devel/setup.bash
#source /usr/share/drcsim/setup.sh

#manually added PYTHONPATH for catkin_make
#export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3.8
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7

export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
```

I try to install pip using [this site](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/), but when running the python get-pip.py command, it results in:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 184
    file = sys.stderr)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This makes sense because I am calling python2.7 but it using python3.8. I dont know how to fix this.

Anyway, back to the main problem, I installed matplotlib and imported it in a python script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16])
plt.show()
```

The result of running that script with python3 is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    import distutils.sysconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
```

The problem with this is when I try to install python3-distutils or python-distutils from apt, apt cant find it. I have python3-distutils-extra and python-distutils-extra installed from apt as well.

I found [a possible solution](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5356) but running the commands

```
python3 -c "import sysconfig"
python3 -c "from distutils import sysconfig as distutils_sysconfig"
```

provided no help. [Another possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810521/how-to-install-python-distutils) did not work either. I created a new python file and copied the script in, but I got a few errors. I fixed a few, but there are too many.

**I think I have a few problems,**

First is that python versions are all confused. When I need python2.7 to install things, like python get-pip.py, it is using python3.8. When asking what version pip3 is, it is calling a file in python 2.7. I think the solution might be something to do with the environment variables but i dont know.

Second, python3.8 might not be installed correctly. I would reinstall it, but i am aware that I could very will mess up my OS.
I also have python3, and python 3.5 installed trying to fix this. I hope this isn't an issue as the PYTHONPATH env variable does not point to either of these

Third, pip is not installed correctly. I have tried a few solutions to this and none have worked.

I appreciate any help you are able to provide, thank you!